# Выровнять активный пункт меню по центру страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Есть меню не известной шириной, которое скрывает родительский блок.
В меню имеется активный элемент, который может находиться как вначале так и в конце списка.

И собственно вопрос, как подвинуть меню, что бы активный пункт меню был всегда по центру окна, если ширина браузера меньше 768рх?

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста код этого меню, желательно со стилями, чтобы понимать как оно выглядит.

Comment: Покажите код, без него вам помочь невозможно.